# How to store images in cache?

Tags: iphone

in iphone i have requirement of store image in cache .

but how i can store this in cache.

I know the folder path of cache. is this only way i have to WRITE my image in that folder for cache?

I want to know any other way. or is this correct way?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this link..

> http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/image-caching-in-iphone-sdk/

edited:
get file path using this code and fatch the particular file :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: i know this way. i asked that is this only way ? i cant do this by any other way ?

Comment: i want to here this thing.i like to know that. can you please tell how can i do that ?

Comment: get the file path useing this :  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: ohh no no apple reject my application for this. they told in front you are talking store data in cache and you are using other library so i have to store in this library. but i am finding is this default way to store it ? if no then i will use WRITE way.

Comment: use temporary dir instead of LibraryDirectory , save temporary dir is the better way because as per the new guideline of apple, we should to save data in temporary dir is more acceptable
use this:                                                                     
NSString *tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
 NSString *tmpFilename = @"XXXXX";
 NSString *tmpPath = [tmpDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpFilename];

Comment: thanks kulss .i think this is the final way. Let me use this only.

Answer (score 2):

You can store data on local disk using `NSArchiver` and `NSUnarchiver` in this way:

// set your image in cache

```
NSData *imgData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myImage];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:imgData forKey:@"img_01"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

//get your image from cache

```
NSData *imgData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"img_01"];
myImage = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:imgData];
```

Reference apple here: http://goo.gl/XH2o2

hope this helps.

Comment: -1 Explanation: NSUserDefaults is not a global storage. NSUserDefaults should be solely used for preferences. But because of the singleton design, people think NSUserDefaults is the successor of the AppDelegate-Superstorage. It's easy to use, available everywhere and "It just works", though. But It's very bad to do so. NSUserDefaults saves its content to a single plist file. And because of this the suggestion to build a cache (= more than one image, probably thousands) with NSUserDefaults as a backend is a bad answer.

Comment: But if you'll do that kind of cache, just for a few images, it'll work so good. I use that in production, for a little time cache, and it works without any problem.